# Is there a correct way to do routerLink in Angular 9?

Tags: angular9

```
<li><a href="" routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a></li>
```

I want to refer Admin component when I click this 'Admin' link which is in the home_page_component.html.But when it is clicked page not found appeared in the admin page.Why is that?. How can I refer another component from another component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to provide routes so that the `admin` is valid path. This is comprehensive tutorial about angular routing https://angular.io/guide/router